# Visual Studio 2012 Fatal error 0x80131c39

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am going bloody insane, I have installed a different type of Windows 8 (pro) at work, and now VS12 gives me this error. At home I have home edition W8 and everything works fine. I found ONLY ONE PERSON encountering this error EVER in Google, and he solved this by switching to .Net 3.5. But I am running an XNA 4.0 game (with a hack to make it work on VS12) and I don't have this option. Has anyone else EVER encountered something like this?

[image: FatalBloddyError]

Comment: Does it happen with *all* projects? Or just a specific one?

Comment: The underlying error is CORDBG_E_MISMATCHED_CORWKS_AND_DACWKS_DLLS.  Gobbledegook that states that there is a fatal mismatch between the CLR version and the debugger version.  That's hard to do, your machine is probably pretty messed up.  Or that "hack" you mentioned isn't that innocent.

Comment: A. It happened with ALL projects as far as I remember that used .Net 4+. You could solve it the way I mentioned but in my case I could not change the targeted .Net framework as I used XNA. B. The machine was not messed up it was a clean install of Win8 64 bit pro and the hack worked at my home machine with Win8 64 bit maximum. Well I solved the problem by going back to Win7 but I think this topic should be left unanswered just in case more ppl end up encountering it.